# Why isn't this `RecurrenceTable` working?

Tags: recursion

I want to evaluate a system of simple recursive equations using `ReccurenceTable` but for a reason that escapes me, I am not able to get it to work. Here is the input.

```
Clear[c0, s0, m, w, \[Eta],y, c, s, t, simul2]
c0 = 25;
s0 = 20;
m = .75;
w = .3;
\[Eta] = .2;
simul2 = RecurrenceTable[{y[t] == (c[t - 1] + \[Eta]*(c[t - 1] - c[t - 2]))*(1 + w) + s0 - s[t - 1], s[t] == s0 + (c[t - 1] + \[Eta]*(c[t - 1] - c[t - 2]))*(1 + w) - c[t], c[t] == c0 + m*y[t], y[0] == 105, y[1] == 105, c[0] == 103.75, c[1] == 103.75, s[0] == 50, s[1] == 50}, {y, s, c}, {t,2,20}]
```

The only output I get following this is simply the input itself. I don't understand why I don't get a list out of this input, as I have already done it with similar equations and had no problem at all. I tweaked the parameters for over an hour for it to work and had absolutely no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear[c0, s0, m, w, η, y, c, s, t, simul2]
c0 = 25;
s0 = 20;
m = 3/4;
w = 3/10;
η = 1/5;
```

Using [`RSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html)

```
soln = RSolve[{y[t] == (c[t - 1] + η*(c[t - 1] - c[t - 2]))*(1 + w) + 
       s0 - s[t - 1], 
     s[t] == s0 + (c[t - 1] + η*(c[t - 1] - c[t - 2]))*(1 + w) - c[t], 
     c[t] == c0 + m*y[t], y[0] == 105, y[1] == 105, c[0] == 415/4, 
     c[1] == 415/4, s[0] == 50, s[1] == 50},
    {y[t], s[t], c[t]}, t] // Simplify[#, t >= 0] &;
```

**EDIT:** Using [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) to obtain an explicitly real form

```
solnN = soln[[1]] // N // ComplexExpand // Simplify // Chop

(*  {c[t] -> 100. + 1.41231 0.187461^t + 2.33769 1.01991^t Cos[0.556027 t] + 
   2.71244 1.01991^t Sin[0.556027 t], 
 s[t] -> 50. - 0.108611 0.187461^t - 1.14139 1.01991^t Cos[0.556027 t] + 
   1.87454 1.01991^
    t Sin[0.556027 t] + (1.71832 + 0.00970207 0.187461^t - 
      0.478024 1.01991^t Cos[0.556027 t] + 
      0.235722 1.01991^t Sin[0.556027 t]) UnitStep[-1. t], 
 y[t] -> 100. + 1.88307 0.187461^t + 3.11693 1.01991^t Cos[0.556027 t] + 
   3.61659 1.01991^t Sin[0.556027 t]}  *)
```

Given the complexity of the solution it is likely that [`RecurrenceTable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html) is timing out before arriving at a solution.

```
Table[{t, y[t], s[t], c[t]} /. solnN, {t, 0, 20}] // 
  Prepend[#, {"t", "y[t]", "s[t]", "c[t]"}] & // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

Comment: I made a mistake in the question, I wrote `y[1] == 105, y[2] == 105` instead of `y[0]==105, y[1]==105`. With this correction, the output for what you wrote is: `{y[2] == 104.875, s[2] == 154.875 - c[2], c[2] == 25 + 0.75 y[2]}`. However, even with this correction, the `ReccurenceTable` still doesn't work.

Comment: So from what I understand, `RecurrenceTable` is to be used only when the system of difference equations is relatively simple?